# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six' - python 3.8.5

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, windows-10, six

When trying to open jupyter notebook from my terminal in Visual Studio Code, I keep getting the error below. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling six using `conda install` but the same issue persists. It was working fine yesterday so I don't know what happened between now and then. I'm using Python 3.8.5 in my virtual environment. Any ideas what could be the issue?

```
(dreams) C:\Users\jacks\Documents\dreams_project>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jacks\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\jacks\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 83, in <module>
    from .services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager, AsyncMappingKernelManager
  File "C:\Users\jacks\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 18, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.session import Session
  File "C:\Users\jacks\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\session.py", line 41, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.jsonutil import extract_dates, squash_dates, date_default
  File "C:\Users\jacks\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\jsonutil.py", line 10, in <module>
    from dateutil.parser import parse as _dateutil_parse
  File "C:\Users\jacks\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ._parser import parse, parser, parserinfo, ParserError
  File "C:\Users\jacks\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 42, in <module>
    import six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
```

Comment: did you installed six inside virtual environment "dreams"?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, six was showing as installed by conda and loading fine when imported manually in python. The base version of Jupyter Notebook would load, but Jupyter Notebook wouldn't load in my virtual environment.

Running `pip3 install six` from a terminal with my environment activated seemed to solve the issue but I don't know why!

Also make sure the path to Conda in the VS Python extension settings is correct.